# What is the name of the optimization algorithm that uses random sampling?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, random-sampling

I am generating random weight as per e.g. below. The I generate a set of 3 values say 100, 250, 300 and I multiple them with the weights below

Initial population.

```
1. 0.1 0.7 0.2

2. 0.4 0.5 0.1

3. 0.3 0.5 0.2

4. 0.6 0.1 0.3

5  0.3 0.3 0.4

6. 0.2 0.2 0.6
```

Multiplication of weight

```
1. 0.1*100 + 0.7*250 + 0.2*300 = 245

2. 0.4*100 + 0.5*250 + 0.1*300 = 195

3. 0.3*100 + 0.5*250 + 0.2*300 = 215

4. 0.6*100 + 0.1*250 + 0.3*300 = 175

5. 0.3*100 + 0.3*250 + 0.4*300 = 225

6. 0.2*100 + 0.2*250 + 0.6*300 = 250
```

So after the multiplication we selected the individual 6 as the best combination of weights. This method works fine for us but we are trying to link it to any available algorithm. Does this algorithm have a specific name? Any idea or help on this?  Is this not a genetic algorithm?

Comment: Hi biz14 and welcome to scicomp!  It's a bit difficult to understand what problem you're working on and what your specific question is.  Rewriting it with more explicit detail will help us to help you better.

Comment: @Paul sorry for my question I have rewrite with clearer steps and problem. Thank you.

Comment: It is clear that your *objective* is to find the maximum dot product between "populations" and "weights" given a fixed vector of "weights".  However, your *constraints* are not clear.  Are you restricting yourself to find a maximum only among the randomly generated "populations"?  Or are you really looking for a maximum among ***all*** feasible values of "population" triplets?

Comment: My constraint is that the weight are calculated using a sum formula from 3 different input which I think pretty much straight forward. Yes my restriction is the finding best among the population of the triplets ? So what is your suggestion?

Comment: My answer below remains the same.

Comment: @Paul thank you let me explore further first those algorithm and update you which I select for you input. Actually my solution is working good but just that I need to give the algorithm a name.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you like the answer, please up-vote it.  If you feel that it answers your question sufficiently, please accept it as the definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you have chosen for your optimization problem sounds like a variant of the family of algorithms known as [random optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_optimization).

I'd like to also add that since your objective and constraints seem to both be linear (please correct me if I'm wrong), your problem can be casted as a [Linear Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem, which is a well studied problem with more efficient algorithms than the one you propose.